# How to receive sms only with my app in monodroid?

Tags: mono, notifications, sms, xamarin, broadcast

sorry, I can't speak good ENG.
I want to make an application with xamarin (Monodroid) and receive sms with that.
How can i disable other apps sms notifications?
in eclipse can use of "abortBroadcast()",but mono dosent have that function.
Plz help me its realy important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BroadcastReceiver.InvokeAbortBroadcast()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAndroid.Content.BroadcastReceiver/%2a) method.